# When was the word co-ord first used?

Tags: etymology, history

The word co-ord means

> [one of two or more pieces of clothing that are made in matching colours or styles so that they can be worn together](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coord)

When was this word first used in this sense?

Comment: Here's an instance of "co-ords" in the relevant sense from a [J.C. Penney's](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19550617.1.5&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522co%252Dords%252522-------1) ad in the _San Bernardino [California] Sun_ (June 17, 1955): "Value! Blouse 'n' Skirt Color **Co-ords** $1.00 blouse $2.00> skirts."

Comment: @SvenYargs I am only interested in the truncated form but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is an abbreviation of *co-ordinates*, which itself likely comes from *coordinated outfit*. The Oxford English Dictionary traces a specific usage for women's clothes to the late 1950s ("[co-ordinate, adj. and n](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/41062)," 3):

> *plural*. A set of women's clothes matched as to colour or fabric or other features.
>
> 1959   Vogue Mar. (advt.) 120   Knitwear and Tweed **Co-ordinates**..by Munrospun.
>
> 1962   Punch 14 Mar. p. xiii.   Harrods have French beachwear, cashmere **co-ordinates**.
>
> 1969   Sears, Roebuck Catal. Spring–Summer 143/2 (heading)    **Coordinates** in cool cotton fabrics.

For instance, here is the term in a snippet from a 1959 ad ([Evening Star, 2 April 1959, page A-10, via Chronicling America](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1959-04-02/ed-1/seq-10/)):

[image]

The abbreviation could have happened as soon as the word was understood, since *co-ord* is generally an abbreviation of *co-ordinate*. This snippet from a 1960 ad shows the adjective form abbreviated as "misses' co-ord. shirt and short sets" (from New York Times, 30 Apr 1960, p. 7, via ProQuest):

> [image]

The earliest example I've found as a noun is from 1955, "CO-ORDS" in a list with "SKIRTS," "JUMPERS," and other items (The Atlanta Constitution, 24 Nov 1955, p. 2, via ProQuest):

[image]

That suggests there are earlier examples of both *co-ordinates* and, possibly, *co-ords* to find.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think the truncated form  is uniquely US until much more recently?

Comment: @graffe In [British Newspaper Archive](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/), I can find a 6 January 1967 ad in Bury Free Press for "CO-ORD SETS Skirt and Blouse," as well as a 9 October 1964 ad in Cheshire Observer for "dresses and co-ords." I can't see details (paywall), but there's at least some evidence it was across the pond in the 1960s.